# how to do SVD using the covariance matrix

Tags: matrices, svd, covariance

I have an $(N \times M)$ matrix $A$ with $M \gg N$, $M$ being millions and $N$ hundreds, and I want to do $SVD$ on the matrix $A$. Can I do this calculation using $A\cdot A$ (the covariance matrix)?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Once you built $A^TA$ the left hand side singular vectors are lost. You can only solve it for the right vectors. Of course square root of eigenvalues will be your singular values.

Comment: If, e.g., $A$ is a tall matrix, then $A=U\Sigma V^T$ where $U$ has a same shape as $A$, $V$ is square. Then from the eigen-decomposition $A^TA$, one can obtain $\Sigma$ and $V$. Assuming $\Sigma$ is invertible, $U=AV\Sigma^{-1}$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I understand the question that finally you have only $A^TA$ matrix.Keeping $A$ of course solves the problem. But this does not make a big sense since SVD on the original matrix is faster IMHO, than building $A^TA$ and recovering $U$ after this.Plus you loosing precision for matrix close to singular.